# OpenCV, vocabulary matrix obtained by BOWKMeansTrainer

Tags: c++, opencv, k-means

I'm trying to follow [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/619039/Bag-of-Features-Descriptor-on-SIFT-Features-with-O) code to implement a BoF. In particular from this code:

```
//featuresUnclustered contains all the feature descriptors of all images
//Construct BOWKMeansTrainer
//the number of bags
int dictionarySize=200;
//define Term Criteria
TermCriteria tc(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER,100,0.001);
//retries number
int retries=1;
//necessary flags
int flags=KMEANS_PP_CENTERS;
//Create the BoW (or BoF) trainer
BOWKMeansTrainer bowTrainer(dictionarySize,tc,retries,flags);
//cluster the feature vectors
cout<<"starting k-means..."<<endl;
Mat dictionary=bowTrainer.cluster(featuresUnclustered);    
//store the vocabulary
FileStorage fs("dictionary.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
fs << "vocabulary" << dictionary;
fs.release();
```

I obtain the `dictionary.yaml` file of the form:

```
%YAML:1.0
vocabulary: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 200
   cols: 128
   dt: f
   data: [ 8.19999981e+00, 1.20000005e+00, 1., 24., 5.82000008e+01,
   ...
   ]
```

Now, my question is: each row represents a centroid (and we have 200 centroids, given by `dictionarySize`) and since SIFT's descriptor size is 128 bit, each centroid has the same dimension. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Each row represents a centroid (and we have 200 centroids, given by `dictionarySize`) and since SIFT's descriptor size is 128 bit, each centroid has the same dimension. Is that correct?

Yes, correct.

Well, SIFT has 128 values (not *bit*). In OpenCV each value is `float`, i.e. 32 bit. But yes, each centroid has 128 values.

---

The `K` of k-means (`dictionarySize`) is the number of centroids. Each centroid has the same dimensionality `N` of the features you use, so 128 for SIFT.

The dictionary will be a matrix `K x N`, in this case `200 X 128`.

---

Remember that the BoW histogram (which is the global descriptor computed using the dictionary) will have `K` values.

Comment: Ooops, my fault! That was the case if we were talking about a binary descriptor though, like ORB ;)

Comment: I mean, supposing that the binary descriptor is in 128 dimensions (and so 128 bits). Just sayin'.